# git merge modifies executable permission

Tags: git, permissions, merge, executable

We're seeing an odd behavior where once and a while, all of our executable files will have their permissions change.  The permissions change from 755 to 644, rendering them useless (until someone goes and chmods them back to executables).  We honestly don't know why this happens, but we suspect it occurs during merge conflicts on Windows systems.

E.G,

commit A had changes for files A and B
commit B had changes for files A and C

the merge of A and B produces a conflict in A.  Yet a git status shows modifications for A,B,C...and all or most of our executable files losing their executable-ness.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before?  If so, how did you solve it?

Thanks,

Ken

Comment: Are you using msysgit, or git with Cygwin? What '`umask`' returns in your bash shell session?

Comment: hey we're using msysgit, and umask returns 0000.  what does that mean?

Comment: That means the default mask for the rights might not be a valid one. Try `umask 755` (or it can means that msysgit doesn't use umask)

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me

```bsh
echo 'git config core.filemode false 2>/dev/null' >> .bash_profile
```